# Can I ask the OP to mark my post as Answer if he forgot to

Tags: support

My response to a question which resolved the issue was not marked as Answer by the OP.

[image]

In the above scenario, it is clear that my post hit directly at the issue and was the only solution to the issue. From the comment it is obvious that the user is clear in identifying that this response is the answer. But it is not marked as Answer.

I just took the liberty of reminding the OP to mark it as answer if it really helped him resolving the issue. Did I do anything wrong. If he still doesn't mark it as answer, shall I have to ignore it. What else shall I have to do or not to do?